# Structuring a 'User-Followers" Node in Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Firebase Database I have a `user-followers` node which holds user IDs along with all IDs of the users they follow

```
user-followers
  -F2iRZkwfuTcKUvd7uYD0jwWeJ7T2
    -KgkkWy5xesvcFcL9GMh: true
    -KgkoZpD0GP687J_5Zh5: true
    -KglKYB8Fcfbc-uwsqwX: true
```

When I fetch the list of a user's followers, I'll need to also fetch some of the followers information, such as their username, profile pic url, etc. That data structure looks like this

```
users
  -KgkkWy5xesvcFcL9GMh
    -image_url: "http://someurl.png"
    -username: "coold00d55'
    //etc...
```

What would be the best solution to accomplish this? Currently I can only think of

1) Fetching an array of followers

2) Performing a lookup of each users info individually, via a `forEach()`

To me this seems sub-optimal. Is there a better way? Perhaps I'd benefit storing the username and image_url under `user-followers` as well?

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid options. Only suggestion I would have would be for your second idea (storing username and image_url) be under a different node so your user-followers one is clean in case you don't want that data. Depending on how often you want to access the data the second idea might be better if high throughput is needed. The only added work would be that you then have to write code to make sure that the other list is always updated (perhaps you can use the new functions available for firebase).

Comment: The second option is a good approach, but if a user updates their profile (their profile pic or user name), the user-followers data will immediately become stale/out of date. Could this be combated?

Comment: That fact alone makes me think the first option might be the best, even though it'll be retrieving more data. Though I could always page the amount of users retrieved. Catch 22's everywhere I turn : |

Comment: I touched on that in the second part of my answer. "The only added work would be that you then have to write code to make sure that the other list is always updated"

Comment: yeah i believe you are correct. I discovered Firebase Functions which seem to be the best route for this.

Comment: I have been experimenting with them for proposes exactly like this.